# MonetDB causing disk space to fill up

Tags: monetdb

I have a bunch of test queries which I am testing against MonetDB. Queries all by itself run fine but if you run the same set of queries in a loop disk runs out of space. I am not sure why would memory map files won't clean up automatically and why do we have to start the server again to clean up these files? Is there a workaround to this problem or is this a known issue in MonetDB?

Comment: on windows?  try closing and re-opening mserver during your loop

Comment: It is on CentOs. Is this a desired behavior to repeatedly reopen mserver?

Comment: There was a memory leak issue in the Oct2014 release. A new version of the code 'July2015' has resolved those issues and works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a memory leak issue in the Oct2014 release. A new version of the code 'July2015' has resolved those issues and works fine.